# SSIS - TaskHost object - Database schemas

Tags: c#, ssis

How would one be able to use a TaskHost object within C# (I use it inside an SSIS scripting task, but this should apply to C# in general as well) and deal with tables that are not in the "dbo" schema?

I have written code that basically connects to a source and a destination database, and then is supposed to bring across specific tables (inside a loop) one by one, both the table-schemas and the data.

On my localhost, this works just peachy, but at my client, the supplier is using schemas; not something we took into account originally, and this is giving me some trouble.

I have tried using the "SchemasList" property of the TaskHost object, but keep running into the same error:

```
? child.Errors[0]
{Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError}
    base {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsObject}: {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError}
    Description: "Table \"[theSchema].[theTable]\" does not exist at the    source.\r\n"
ErrorCode: -1073548445
HelpContext: 0
HelpFile: ""
IDOfInterfaceWithError: "{B6F6D221-FC27-4F71-B5A0-597583986C28}"
Source: "{D6DF0C1F-0AC8-4748-836C-BEF052454AEE}"
SubComponent: "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task"
TimeStamp: {16-07-2012 13:41:43}
```

Here's the code:

```
if (Dts.Variables["tableName"].Value.ToString() != "0") {
        string tableName;
        tableName = Dts.Variables["tableName"].Value.ToString();

        // Add a child package 
        Package child = new Package();

        child.Name = tableName;
        Executable moveTable = child.Executables.Add("STOCK:TransferSQLServerObjectsTask");
        TaskHost moveTableTask = (TaskHost)moveTable;

        // Set properties for the task
        moveTableTask.Properties["CopyAllObjects"].SetValue(moveTableTask, false);
        moveTableTask.Properties["CopyAllTables"].SetValue(moveTableTask, false);
        moveTableTask.Properties["CopySchema"].SetValue(moveTableTask, true);
        moveTableTask.Properties["DropObjectsFirst"].SetValue(moveTableTask, true);
        moveTableTask.Properties["CopyData"].SetValue(moveTableTask, true);

        // Set schemas
        //StringCollection schemas = new StringCollection();
        //String[] schemaList = new String[] {"[theSchema].[" + tableName + "]"};
        //schemas.AddRange(schemaList);
        //moveTableTask.Properties["SchemasList"].SetValue(moveTableTask, schemas);

        // Set tablenames
        StringCollection tables = new StringCollection();
        tables.Add(tableName);
        moveTableTask.Properties["TablesList"].SetValue(moveTableTask, tables);

        // Set up connections
        ConnectionManager source;
        ConnectionManager destination;

        source = child.Connections.Add("SMOServer");
        source.ConnectionString = "SqlServerName=*****;UseWindowsAuthentication=False;UserName=*****;Password=*****;";
        source.Name = "Source";

        destination = child.Connections.Add("SMOServer");
        destination.ConnectionString = "SqlServerName=*****;Persist Security Info=True;Password=*****;USER ID=*****;Initial Catalog=*****";
        destination.Name = "Destination";
        moveTableTask.Properties["SourceConnection"].SetValue(moveTableTask, "Source");
        moveTableTask.Properties["SourceDatabase"].SetValue(moveTableTask, "*****");
        moveTableTask.Properties["DestinationConnection"].SetValue(moveTableTask, "Destination");
        moveTableTask.Properties["DestinationDatabase"].SetValue(moveTableTask, "*****");

        child.Execute();

        child.Dispose();
```

As you can see, there is a commented bit which was an attempt to see if I could add the schema that way. Another option I tried was using the CopyAllSchemas property, but that also did nothing.

I also tried adding the schema in the line of code where the tablename is added to the tables stringcollection, but that yields the same error, regardless of using square brackets ([]) or not. It seems the TaskHost by default only accepts tables in the "dbo" schema, unless I am missing something.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could get the TaskHost to handle the database schema?

Comment: In your commented code, it seems you were building out the values for the `schemaList` such that it was schema.table What if you just specified the schema there? That'd be in-line with the assignment for table names you have below.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried using that before as well, and only referred to the above after not getting any proper result. This really is killing me as it's the last missing link in the project.

Comment: I just double-checked and did a bit more testing on my localmachine. Running profiler to capture what's being sent to the SQL Server, I see the following:

    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) AS [Schema],
tbl.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
WHERE
(tbl.name=@_msparam_0 and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_1)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'tableName',@_msparam_1=N'dbo'

This is even when using SchemasList with the proper schema in it, and ensuring that CopyAllSchemas was set to false.

Comment: It seems as if the SMO object somehow does default to the dbo user. Another clue in the trace reveals the following statement: 

`SELECT
(select default_schema_name from sys.database_principals where name = user_name()) AS [DefaultSchema]`

and username() will default to dbo, even when using windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the tables were not tables, but views.Using a combination of a Views collection, and some additional tweakings with the schemas I managed to get things to work :)